# Struggling with a dynamic pivot on multiple columns with one being concatenated

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table with data like so:

```
Employee    PRDate    Type    Code    Amount    Subject    Eligible
1234        1/1/2015  D       1       100.00    100.00     0.00
1234        1/1/2015  D       2       200.00    0.00       0.00
5678        1/1/2015  D       1       500.00    40.00      500.00
1234        1/1/2015  E       1       300.00    30.00      300.00
5678        1/1/2015  E       1       700.00    700.00     500.00
1234        1/1/2015  E       2       400.00    200.00     0.00
1234        1/8/2015  L       55      40.00     40.00      40.00
```

And I need for the data to be displayed like this:

```
Employee PRDate    D1Amt  D1Subj  D1Elig  D2Amt  D2Subj  D2Elig  E1Amt  E1Subj E1Elig E2Amt  E2Subj E2Elig L55Amt L55Subj L55Elig
1234     1/1/2015  100.00 100.00  0.00    200.00 0.00    0.00    300.00 30.00  300.00 400.00 200.00 0.00   40.00  40.00   40.00
4678     1/1/2015  500.00 40.00   500.00                         700.00 700.00 500.00
```

I can pivot on one column but when I try combining the Type and Code columns to get the one I get conversion errors (Type is a varchar and code is a tinyint). I'm not sure how to get to the desired results other than dynamic pivot. Can the desired results be achieved?

I've gotten this far but I can't figure out how to combine the type, code and each money columns (amount, subject and eligible) to get the data under the correct columns.

```
IF EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM sys.tables
WHERE name LIKE '#temp285865%')
DROP TABLE #temp285865;
Create table dbo.#temp285865
(
    EDLCodetemp varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #temp285865
(
    [EDLCodetemp]
)
SELECT DISTINCT EDLCode
FROM #results
ORDER BY EDLCode;

-- Building a comma separated list of EDLCodes in #edltemp
DECLARE @cols varchar(1000);
SELECT @cols = COALESCE(@cols + ',[' + [EDLCodetemp] + ']', '[' +  [EDLCodetemp] + ']')
FROM #temp285865;

-- Building the query appending columns
DECLARE @query varchar(4000);
SET @query =
'SELECT [CoName],
        [PRCo],
        [PRGroup],
        [PREndDate],
        [PaySeq],
        [EDLType],
        [Hours],
        [SubjectAmt],
        [EligibleAmt],
        [PaidMth],
        [LastName],
        [FirstName],
        [UseOver],
        [OverAmt],
        [Amount],
        [PRGRDescrip],
        [LimitPeriod],
        [LimitMth],
        [PREHEmployee],
        [SortName],
        [PaybackAmt],
        [PaybackOverAmt],
        [PaybackOverYN],
        [PRDTEmployee],
        [TrueEarns], '
        + @cols + ' FROM 
(
    SELECT  [CoName],
            [PRCo],
            [PRGroup],
            [PREndDate],
            [PaySeq],
            [EDLType],
            [Hours],
            [SubjectAmt],
            [EligibleAmt],
            [PaidMth],
            [LastName],
            [FirstName],
            [PRDLDescrip],
            [PRECDescrip],
            [UseOver],
            [OverAmt],
            [Amount],
            [PRGRDescrip],
            [LimitPeriod],
            [LimitMth],
            [PREHEmployee],
            [SortName],
            [PaybackAmt],
            [PaybackOverAmt],
            [PaybackOverYN],
            [PRDTEmployee],
            [TrueEarns],
            [EDLCode]
    FROM    #results
) p
PIVOT (  
  MAX(EDLCode) 
  FOR [EDLCode] IN (' + @cols + ')
)
as pvt';

EXEC(@query);

DROP TABLE #temp285865;
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I tried fixing that myself but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following PIVOT with dynamic SQL would give you the result you want, based on the input data you provided (I changed the PRDate in the last row though).

The first statement builds an intermediate table `#bt` with the column names you want and the associated value. Then the column names are built in `@cols` for the dynamic SQL statement. Finally the intermediate table `#bt` is pivoted with a dynamic SQL statement using the `@cols` to pivot.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

CREATE TABLE #t(
    Employee INT,
    PRDate DATETIME,
    Type CHAR(1),
    Code TINYINT,
    Amount DECIMAL(28,2),
    Subject DECIMAL(28,2),
    Eligible DECIMAL(28,2)
);

INSERT INTO #t(Employee,PRDate,Type,Code,Amount,Subject,Eligible)VALUES(1234,'2015-01-01','D',1,100.00,100.00,0.00);
INSERT INTO #t(Employee,PRDate,Type,Code,Amount,Subject,Eligible)VALUES(1234,'2015-01-01','D',2,200.00,0.00,0.00);
INSERT INTO #t(Employee,PRDate,Type,Code,Amount,Subject,Eligible)VALUES(5678,'2015-01-01','D',1,500.00,40.00,500.00);
INSERT INTO #t(Employee,PRDate,Type,Code,Amount,Subject,Eligible)VALUES(1234,'2015-01-01','E',1,300.00,30.00,300.00);
INSERT INTO #t(Employee,PRDate,Type,Code,Amount,Subject,Eligible)VALUES(5678,'2015-01-01','E',1,700.00,700.00,500.00);
INSERT INTO #t(Employee,PRDate,Type,Code,Amount,Subject,Eligible)VALUES(1234,'2015-01-01','E',2,400.00,200.00,0.00);
INSERT INTO #t(Employee,PRDate,Type,Code,Amount,Subject,Eligible)VALUES(1234,'2015-01-01','L',55,40.00,40.00,40.00);

SELECT
    Employee,
    PRDate,
    Type+CAST(Code AS VARCHAR(3))+ca.name AS colname,
    ca.val
INTO
    #bt
FROM
    #t
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT Amount AS val,'Amt' AS name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Subject AS val,'Subj' AS name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Eligible AS val,'Elig' AS name
    ) AS ca;

/* If you need to SUM for all dates, instead use this statement to create #bt
SELECT
    Employee,
    Type+CAST(Code AS VARCHAR(3))+ca.name AS colname,
    ca.val
INTO
    #bt
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            Employee,
            Type,
            Code,
            SUM(Amount) AS Amount,
            SUM(Subject) AS Subject,
            SUM(Eligible) AS Eligible
        FROM
            #t
        GROUP BY
            Employee,
            Type,
            Code
    ) AS t
    CROSS APPLY(
        SELECT Amount AS val,'Amt' AS name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Subject AS val,'Subj' AS name
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Eligible AS val,'Elig' AS name
    ) AS ca;
*/

DECLARE @cols VARCHAR(8000);
SET @cols=STUFF(
    (SELECT DISTINCT
        ',['+colname+']'
    FROM
        #bt
    FOR XML PATH('')),
    1,
    1,
    ''
);

DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql='
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        #bt
        PIVOT(
            MAX(val)
            FOR colname IN ('+@cols+')
        ) AS piv
';

EXEC (@sql);

DROP TABLE #bt;
DROP TABLE #t;
```

The result is the following:

```
Employee    PRDate  D1Amt   D1Elig  D1Subj  D2Amt   D2Elig  D2Subj  E1Amt   E1Elig  E1Subj  E2Amt   E2Elig  E2Subj  L55Amt  L55Elig L55Subj
1234    2015-01-01 100.00   0.00    100.00  200.00  0.00    0.00    300.00  300.00  30.00   400.00  0.00    200.00  40.00   40.00   40.00
5678    2015-01-01 500.00   500.00  40.00   NULL    NULL    NULL    700.00  500.00  700.00  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, where would I throw in a "where" clause to narrow the results down by?

Comment: @DrPepperholik In the first statement which creates the intermediate table `#bt`: `SELECT .. INTO #bt FROM ... WHERE <restrictions>`

Comment: @DrPepperholik If this answers your questions, do me the favor of clicking the checkmark next to the answer :)

Comment: Another question for you. I need to do a sum of the amounts that are in the columns across all PRDates. So if there's 4 PRDates I need to get the D1Amt for all 4 PRDates in the one column. How do I do this?

Comment: @DrPepperholik I have edited the query, and added a part in between /* */. Replace the query before that with the new query to SUM for all dates. I hope that is quite enough to earn that checkmark :)

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been very helpful! I know I only posted a few codes but there are actually around 100 codes, so this query now gives me around 300 combinations (Type + Code + Amount/Subject/Eligible) and Crystal Reports was doing something weird with the summary fields in there so I had to do the sum in the SP then. This helped so much!

Comment: @DrPepperholik I'm glad it helped. Good luck with the report!

Comment: Thanks, I need it. The SP works fine in SQL Server, in Crystal it works fine, when I deploy it and run through the program it runs fine but the one user who needs the report keeps getting error messages.

Comment: @DrPepperholik If you can't find a solution to the new problem you are facing, I suggest you make a new question on StackOverflow with a detailed description of the problem and the error message you are getting.