# Need to write SSRS report that uses stored procedure with a pivot as a dataset but I can't get the report to be dynamic, is this even possible?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a bear of a problem here. The user wants a report that shows the earnings, deductions and liabilities (EDL) code of each employee or null/blank if an EDL code doesn't apply to that employee. I needed one row for each employee name and columns for each possible EDL code combination. I got that answer fixed from my previous question here:

[Struggling with a dynamic pivot on multiple columns with one being concatenated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29752899/struggling-with-a-dynamic-pivot-on-multiple-columns-with-one-being-concatenated)

I ran into a problem where there are a potential 270 column headings (EDL code combination with "subj", "elig" or "amt" appended) but not every employee will have a value for every column and security settings lock me out of seeing 1 of the 3 payroll groups. This made my report very limited in that when I ran it I could only show on the Crystal Report the data for what columns I had at the time I created the Crystal Report. Well, the user who requested this report has access to payroll group 1 and if even one of those employees had an EDL code that I didn't have in my data when I created the Crystal Reports file then the report wasn't useful to the user. We figured a way for her to get the info she needed by her logging into SQL Server and executing the stored procedure and she did what she needed to do with the data.

Fast forwarding to today I have to create this as a report in SSRS or give detailed instructions on how she can do this in the future if need be since my contract is coming to an end. I'm not familiar with SSRS but I thought maybe that would meet her needs over Crystal Reports. However, I'm running into the same problem. When I add the stored procedure as a dataset (adding it in as text to execute, not clicking the stored procedure radio button) I only see the EDL codes from that particular query not all potential combinations. I need a way to maybe dynamically add columns to the SSRS report, does such a thing exist?

Comment: A better approach would be to get the data in its raw form (not pivoted) and then use a matrix to display it

Comment: Don't you have to know the column names, all of them, to do a matrix display?

Comment: I tried doing the matrix and just leaving out the pivot portion of the query but I get no results when I run it this way, the query works, just for some reason it isn't working in SSRS. Will SSRS not work with a cross apply?

Comment: The marix is the way of doing the pivot. You choose the field that will be at the top and those field values become the "columns". For example, if you had a query with stores, months, and units sold you would put stores as the row field, month as the column field and SUM(Fields!UnitsSold.Value) as the expression and you would get as many months as there were as the columns.